# How to emulate 500-50000 worker (docker) nodes network?

Tags: docker, networking, virtual-machine, emulation, verification

So I have a worker docker images. I want to spin up a network of 500-50000 nodes to emulate what happens to a private blockchain such as etherium on different scales. What would be a recomendation for an opensource tool/library for such job:

a) one that would make sure that even on a low-endish (say one 40 cores node) all workers will be moved forward in time equaly (not realtime)

b) would allow (a) in a distributed setting (say 10 low-endish nodes on a single lan)

In other words I do not seek for realtime network emulation, so I can wait for 10 hours to simulate 1 minute and it would be good enough fro me. I thought about [Kathara](https://github.com/KatharaFramework/Kathara/blob/master/README.md) yet a problem still stands - how to make sure that say 10000 containers are given the same amount of ticks in a round-robin manner?

So how to emulate a complex network of docker workers?

Comment: You're going to run into lots of limitations trying to run 500-50000 nodes on a single machine. As an example Kubernetes has a limit of 100 pods per node/machine/host. I would imagine your best bet is to spin up a bunch of instances on a cloud provider and test there.

Comment: @maxm: realtime is not what I look for - only equal (in given ticks to nodes) provided time from CPU (in a roun-robin manner) even if to achieve a same tick   time for my 10000 nodes will take an hour... they shall get progress equally.

Comment: Slick idea, the likely limitations and issues with that approach are way beyond my comprehension. You likely want full virtualization though. You can likely control qemu's clock speeds: http://www.miroslavnovak.com/qemu-brake_en.php Qemu might be a good tool to look at generally

Comment: I wonder how the network will be effected, I guess it's just compute. You'd need to slow cpu clock and time itself, and if you screw anything up your test won't be realistic. I'd still price out the cloud option, spot instances are cheap and orchestration is fun :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking the assumption that you will run each inside of a container. To ensure each container runs with similar CPU access, you can configure CPU reservations and limits on each replica. These numbers get computed down to fractional slices of a core, so on an 8 core system, you could give each container 0.01 of a core to run upwards of 800 containers. See the [compose documentation on how to set resource constraints](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources). And with swarm mode, you could spread these replicas across multiple nodes, sharing a network.

That said, I think the advice to run shorter simulations on more hardware is good. You will find a significant portion of the time is spent in context switching between each process, possibly invalidating any measurements you want to take.

You will also encounter scalability issues with docker and the orchestration tool you choose. For example, you'll need to adjust the subnet size for any shared network which defaults to a /24 with around 253 available IP's. The docker engine itself will likely be spending a non-trivial amount of CPU time maintaining the state for all of the running containers.

Comment: Yes, they are all docker images. Does docker cpu options provide any guarantees on instance cpu starvation/liveness scheduling?

Comment: Resource constraint have two settings, reservations and limits. The reservation guarantees that your application will get at least that much of the CPU. And limits prevents the container from using more than a given slice of the CPU. I'm not aware of what will happen if you have reservations equaling 100% of the CPU resources with workload outside of containers also running, would need to be tested.

Comment: All of these settings are configuring the CFS, so reviewing that implementation may be useful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler